# How to remove a category from a variable in R

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a dataset on over 20 variables about tennis matches and one of them is about the floor type.

After removing older years, I came with these types of floors.

```
summary(Data_Analysis$floor_type_draft)

Carpet   Clay  Grass   Hard 
1621     9245    0    10328
```

Since now Grass has no observations, how can I remove this particular category?

I tried this option:

```
Data_Analysis$floor_type_draft <-
 Data_Analysis$floor_type_draft %>% mutate(Data_Analysis=droplevels(Grass))
```

But I got an error.

Do I need to create a data frame?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Data_Analysis <-
  Data_Analysis %>%
  mutate(floor_type_draft=droplevels(floor_type_draft))
```

`mutate` is mande to operate with columns from a data.frame, then there is no need to use the operator `$`.